# React - Alternatives to triggering rerender of specific components after child mounting finishes

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

This is more of a conceptual question than anything else.

I'm trying to draw a SVG line between two elements in my application. The way I'm currently doing this is by having a top level ref, inside of which I store a ref for each of the child elements indexed by an arbitrary key. I then draw the arrows, deduced from a 2 dimensional array of pairs of these keys, look up the ref, and use the positioning of those elements to create the SVG's coordinates.

The problem with this method is, besides initial render, every render update afterwards uses outdated ref data as the children get rendered (and therefore positioned) after the parent, inside which the SVG layer is contained.

I've already thought of the obvious answers, useEffects, setStates, etc., but there doesn't seem to be a good solution here that I can think of. A lot of the obvious answers don't necessarily work in this case since they cause render loops. Another solution that I initially thought of was breaking down the arrow rendering to within each of the children, but this had problems of its own that initially caused the transition to having all of the refs live at the parent level.

My current solution is to key the SVG Layer component to a state variable, and then change the value of this variable in a useEffect once the final item renders, but this solution feels messy and improper.

Not exact but here's some code of the issue

Parent Component:

```js
export default ({ items }) => { 
  const [svgKey, setSvgKey] = useState(0);
  const pairs = items.reduce((arr, item) => {
    for (const subItem of item.subItems) {
      arr.push([subItem, item]);
    }
  }, [])
  const itemRefs = useRef({});

  return (
   <>
     {items.map(item => <Row items={items} setSvgKey={setSvgKey} item={item} refs={refs} key={item.key} />}
     <SVGLayer key={svgKey} pairs={pairs} refs={refs} />
   </>
  );
}
```

SVG Layer

```js
export default ({ pairs, refs }) => (
  <svg>
    {pairs.map(([a, b], i) => (
      <Arrow key={i} a={refs.current[a.key]} b={refs.current[b.key]} />
    )}
  </svg>
);
```

Arrow

```js
export default ({ a, b }) => <path d={[math for line coords here]} />;
```

Row

```js
export default ({ refs, item, items, setSvgKey }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (item.key === items[items.length - 1].key) {
      setSvgKey(key => ++key);
    } 
  });
  return (
    <div ref={el => (refs.current[item.key] = el)}  />
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Updated with minimum viable code examples